# LDAP referral prepending base

Tags: java, spring-security, active-directory, ldap

I am trying to make Spring Security follow referrals with Active Directory. 
All configuration seems to work fine and I am using `dc=example,dc=local` as base

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ldap/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/ldap/core/support/AbstractContextSource.java#L305

but when trying to login to a referenced user it seems to add twice the base:

```
o.s.s.l.a.BindAuthenticator              : Attempting to bind as cn=Euro Dude,cn=Users,dc=eu,dc=example,dc=local,dc=example,dc=local
```

and it obviously fails since it cannot find the user. If, blocking with debugger, I remove the extra `dc=example,dc=local` it logs in fine.

Looking at the code

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/ldap/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/ldap/authentication/BindAuthenticator.java#L115-L118

I saw that it is appending the base LDAP path to the Distinguished Name

```
DistinguishedName userDn = new DistinguishedName(userDnStr);
DistinguishedName fullDn = new DistinguishedName(userDn);
fullDn.prepend(ctxSource.getBaseLdapPath());`
```

Reading documentation I have found
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/referral/jndi.html

> Windows Active Directory: Because Active Directory does not support
>   the Manage Referral control, none of the examples in this lesson will
>   work against Active Directory.

Does it mean that it is not supposed work at all?

Why is the base being added to a full Distinguished Name?
Note that I am *not* providing the user DN, but only the `sAMAccountName` and the DN is taken automatically.

```
o.s.l.c.support.DefaultDirObjectFactory  : Received name 'ldap://eu.example.local:389/CN=Euro%20Dude,CN=Users,DC=eu,DC=example,DC=local' contains protocol delimiter; indicating a referral.Stripping protocol and address info to enable construction of a proper LdapName
o.s.l.c.support.DefaultDirObjectFactory  : Resulting name after removal of referral information: 'CN=Euro Dude,CN=Users,DC=eu,DC=example,DC=local'
o.s.s.ldap.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate    : Found DN: CN=Euro Dude,CN=Users,DC=eu,DC=example,DC=local
o.s.s.l.a.BindAuthenticator              : Attempting to bind as cn=Euro Dude,cn=Users,dc=eu,dc=example,dc=local,dc=example,dc=local
s.s.l.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource : Removing pooling flag for user cn=Euro Dude,cn=Users,dc=eu,dc=example,dc=local,dc=example,dc=local
o.s.s.l.a.BindAuthenticator              : Failed to bind as CN=Euro Dude,CN=Users,DC=eu,DC=example,DC=local: org.springframework.ldap.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C09042F, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v2580
```